# GUI for Kaldi ASR

Tags: software-recommendation, application-development

I'm a graduating student. Our group's thesis is about ASR. In less than a week, we're going to defend it. We've already produced a model for our ASR which we run on Linux. Our problem is we need a graphical user interface to present our output in the panels.

Answer (score 1):

For presenting plots and tabular data to the thesis panel you could use python3-matplotlib python3-pandas and jupyter.

```
sudo apt install python3-matplotlib python3-pandas jupyter
```

Kaldi is written mainly in C/C++, but the toolkit is wrapped with Bash and Python scripts.

[image: Kaldi]

To use Python packages for presentation you can also use an interface between Kaldi and Python, such as py-kaldi-asr and pykaldi.